# Casting a spell with every selected unit

Tags: starcraft-2

Suppose for example I have 13 corruptors selected, and I'd like to have them all cast caustic spray on an enemy command center.

I can do this by `c` `mouseclick` `c` `mouseclick` `c` `mouseclick` `c` `mouseclick` ... (thirteen times), but this is time intensive and can lead to mistakes if done too fast.

Is there a simple way to issue such a command to every unit that I have selected?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortuantely not. Each casted spell requires it's own command. Your easiest way would be to hold the Shift Key, press C, mouse click 13 times.

Comment: Thanks. At least using the shift key in this way saves work compared to the naive approach.

Answer (score 4):

There's a technique called "quickcast". If you set the "cast spell" hotkey (default: click left mouse button) secondary hotkey to [C], then you can press and hold [C] to cast this quickly.

Since Zerg has ravagers that cast Corrosive Bile also with [C], you can use this to cast corrosive bile quickly, too.